# Insert from Two tables to One while duplicates are ignored

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to insert from two MS Access tables into one ms access table.
In one of the two tables there is a column that contains a duplicate value.
What I have at the moment is:

> ```
>  Dim MySQL As String = "INSERT INTO XML_TEST_CASE (" & _
>                                     "TCParmId, " & _
>                                     "TestCase, " & _
>                                     "MessageType, " & _
>                                     "FileNo,  " & _
>                                     "InstructionNo,  " & _
>                                     "TransactionNo,  " & _
>                                     "ElementNo,  " & _
>                                     "MessageSection, " & _
>                                     "ElementLevel, " & _
>                                     "FullElementPath, " & _
>                                     "ElementValue, " & _
>                                     "ElementValueNew, " & _
>                                     "NameSpace, " & _
>                                     "NameSpaceValue, " & _
>                                     "Attribute, " & _
>                                     "AttributeValue, " & _
>                                     "TestCaseDescription) " & _
>                                     "SELECT " & _
>                                     "P.TCParmId, " & _
>                                     "P.TestCase, " & _
>                                     "P.MessageType, " & _
>                                     "P.FileNo, " & _
>                                     "P.InstructionNo, " & _
>                                     "P.TransactionNo, " & _
>                                     "S.ElementNo, " & _
>                                     "S.MessageSection, " & _
>                                     "S.ElementLevel, " & _
>                                     "S.ElementPath + S.Element, " & _
>                                     "S.ElementValue, " & _
>                                     "S.ElementValue, " & _
>                                     "S.NameSpace, " & _
>                                     "S.NameSpaceValue, " & _
>                                     "S.Attribute, " & _
>                                     "S.AttributeValue, " & _
>                                     "P.TestCaseDescription " & _
>                                     "FROM XML_TEST_CASE_PARAMETER P, XML_MESSAGE_STRUCTURE S " & _
>                                     "WHERE S.MessageType = P.MessageType " & _
>                                     "AND P.TestCase = '" & MyTestCase & "' " & _
>                                     "AND P.MessageType = '" & MyMessageType & "' " & _
>                                     "AND P.FileNo = " & MyFileNo & " " & _
>                                     "AND P.InstructionNo = " & MyInstructionNo & " " & _
>                                     "AND P.TransactionNo = " & MyTransactionNo & ";"
> ```

The problem is that in the XML_MESSAGE_STRUCTURE table it happens that S.ElementNo sometimes appreas more than once which then cuasing that I get also more than one records in my destination table for the specific ElementNo. This I do not want.

Any help is appreaciated.

Rico

Comment: The easiest way is to add a unique index to elementNo.

Comment: Are all the othjer fields the same as well? If so, use SELECT DISTINCT. If not, how are you going to choose which record should be inserted and which should be excluded?

Comment: Remou, that is not an option because there will be duplicate elementNo's but only where TCParmID is NOT the same. In other words for each testcase (TCParmID) there should always be just one of each ElementNo.

Comment: Darius, if the first record is selected then it is fine.

Comment: In that case you can have an index that is unique for both fields combined

Comment: Remou, correct! TCParmID and ElementNo are both primary keys with Indexed = Yes(Duplicates OK)

Comment: I mean an index TCParmID + ElementNo = Yes, Duplicates not okay: `create unique index  combined  on tablename ([TCParmID], [ElementNo])`

Comment: Remou, I have changed both to Indexed = Yes(No Duplicates) but I am still getting "the changes to the table were not successful becuase they could create duplicate values in the index, primary key or relationship..."

Comment: No, not two indexes, one index using both fields. For example: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/73521857/key.JPG shows a primary key set by highlighting both fields, but it does not have to be primary.

Comment: Remou, I am not familiar with this command. Could you please guide me as to where and how I should apply this to my insert query

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24835/discussion-between-remou-and-rico-strydom)

Comment: Remou, thank you very much for your help. It is truely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `SELECT DISTINCT`, you could group by all of the fields except ElementNo. For ElementNo, you would select `Max(ElementNo)`:

```
 Dim MySQL As String = "INSERT INTO XML_TEST_CASE (" & _
                                "TCParmId, " & _
                                "TestCase, " & _
                                "MessageType, " & _
                                "FileNo,  " & _
                                "InstructionNo,  " & _
                                "TransactionNo,  " & _
                                "ElementNo,  " & _
                                "MessageSection, " & _
...
                                "SELECT " & _
                                "P.TCParmId, " & _
                                "P.TestCase, " & _
                                "P.MessageType, " & _
                                "P.FileNo, " & _
                                "P.InstructionNo, " & _
                                "P.TransactionNo, " & _
                                "Max(S.ElementNo), " & _
                                "S.MessageSection, " & _
...
                               "FROM XML_TEST_CASE_PARAMETER P, XML_MESSAGE_STRUCTURE S " & _
                                "WHERE S.MessageType = P.MessageType " & _
                                "AND P.TestCase = '" & MyTestCase & "' " & _
                                "AND P.MessageType = '" & MyMessageType & "' " & _
                                "AND P.FileNo = " & MyFileNo & " " & _
                                "AND P.InstructionNo = " & MyInstructionNo & " " & _
                                "AND P.TransactionNo = " & MyTransactionNo & _
                                "GROUP BY " & _
                                "P.TCParmId, " & _
                                "P.TestCase, " & _
                                "P.MessageType, " & _
                                "P.FileNo, " & _
                                "P.InstructionNo, " & _
                                "P.TransactionNo, " & _
                                "S.MessageSection, " & _
...
                                 ";"
```